# SlideUp and Slidedown for each element

Tags: jquery, each, settimeout

I've searched these pages for an answer without luck, despite some answers came close. What I like to write is a function for 5 elements within a parent, looking something like this.

HTML

```
<div id="introOverlay">
  <div id="introSlider-0"></div>    
  <div id="introSlider-1"></div>    
  <div id="introSlider-2"></div>    
  <div id="introSlider-3"></div>    
  <div id="introSlider-4"></div>
</div>
```

Each element should slide up and down (using css transitions, therefore targeting the height) before the next starts. So I try to create a slider, combining multiple functions. Now the delay is calculated by the index of each element, but it makes the transitions differ is speed. How do I get the same speed for each element? I was trying `.queue()` / `.dequeue()`, but how do I combine this with the `setTimeout()`? This is what I've got this far.

jQuery

```
function introSlides() {

    $('#introOverlay div[id^=introSlider]').each(function(i){               

    var slides = $(this);

        // Slide Down
        setTimeout(function() {
            slides.css({'height' : 600});
        }, 3000 * i);

        // Slide Up
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            slides.css({'height' : 0}); 
        }, 4000 * i);                       

   });
}
```

On top of that, how do I set a timeout for the first element? Right now it's getting the second css styling from the start.
What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks for any help or tips!

Comment: you need to bind to `transitionend` or `animationend` and then start the next transition/animation...

Comment: Never heard of this, but checking it out right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Hitmands pointing me in the right direction, I managed to work this out. I'm curious why the first .dequeue() in line 9 doesn't seem to do much.

Script

```
function introSlides() {                
$('#introOverlay div[id^=introSlider]').each(function(i){           

var slides = $(this);                       

// Slide Down
setTimeout(function() {
    slides.css({'height' : 600}).delay(3000).queue(function(){
        $(this).css({'height' : 0}).dequeue();
    });
}, 4000 * i);               

$(this).one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd",

function(e){
// slide Up again
$(this).css({ 'height' : 0 }).dequeue();
});             

});}
```

Probably this code can be improved. Please feel free to respond… I'm still learning. Thanks :)